# Vee validate 4 error won't disappear after submit

Tags: vuejs3, vee-validate

I have a custom component which is the Tiptap editor added to a Form. Now when the page is rendered, the form behaves right but when I made a post request, the form throws a required error. I think I am missing something.

```
<script setup>
  import { useField, Form, useForm } from 'vee-validate'
  import * as yup from 'yup'
  import { useBaseFetch } from '@/composables/api'
  import AppCommentBox from '@/components/elements/AppCommentBox'

  const props = defineProps({
  taskId: {
    type: Number,
    required: true,
  },
  taskMembers: {
    type: Array,
    required: true,
  },
  user: {
    type: Object,
    required: true,
  },
  })

  const { errors, handleSubmit } = useForm({
  validationSchema: yup.object({
    message: yup.string().required('This field is required.'),
  }),
  })

  const { value: message } = useField('message')
  const errorMsg = ref('')
  const currentPage = ref(1)
  const members = ref(props.taskMembers)

  const onSubmit = handleSubmit(async () => {
  await postComment()
  if (!Form.diry) {
    errors.message = ''
  }
  })

  const postComment = async () => {
  const task = props.taskId
  const url = `/tasks/${task}/comments`

  try {
    await useBaseFetch(url, {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
        comment: message.value,
      }),
    })
    message.value = ''
    currentPage.value = 1
    getComments()
  } catch (error) {
    if (error.response && error.response.status === 422) {
      console.log('error', error)
    } else {
      errorMsg.value = 'An error occured.'
    }
  }
  }
</script>
```

```
<template>
<Form @submit="onSubmit">
  <AppCommentBox v-model="message" name="message" :taskmembers="members" placeholder="Type @ to mention and notify a member." />
  <span class="text-red-500 text-sm normal-case">{{ errors.message }}</span>
  <div class="flex gap-2 mt-4">
    <ElementsAppButton size="small" type="submit">
      Save
    </ElementsAppButton>
  </div>
</Form>
</template>
```

Comment: Is `Form.isDiry` a typo in the question or in your actual code?

Comment: Yes it's a typo error. found the solution though. I use the vee-validate resetForm function